# Is there a way to list supported BTRFS compression algorithms?

Tags: linux, btrfs

Or, perhaps a better question would be - is it possible to list all available Btrfs options on the current system? The only way for a Btrfs user to find this out is to check the kernel version, and go through Btrfs changelog and see what is added, what removed etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Btrfs Wiki](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Mount_options) mentions that zlib/lzo were available starting in 2.6.38, and it doesn't appear that any new compression abilities have been added since then. At least on that front, any kernel since 2.6.38 has the same capabilities (and probably earlier, since it looks like the lzo was less stable before then. Unless there's something available in `/sys` or `/proc`, etc. that I'm missing, the `btrfs` and `btrfsctl` tools don't have a way to query it.

Answer (score 2):

As of [kernel 3.14](https://btrfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Feature-by-version.html), feature bits supported by the kernel in `/sys/fs/btrfs/features`. On kernel 5.15, I see `compress_lzo` and `compress_zstd`, indicating that lzo and zstd compression are supported. New compression algorithms will get new feature bits. There is no feature bit for zlib, you just have to know that that is supported as well.